# dynamic_cast derived template to less cv-qualified pointer

Tags: c++, c++11

I've got the following code:

```
struct Base
{
    virtual ~Base(){};
};

template<class T>
struct Derived : public Base
{};

int main()
{
    Derived<int> d;
    Base *pD = &d;

    if(dynamic_cast<Derived<const int>*>(pD))
    {
        std::cout << "const" << std::endl;
    }

    if(dynamic_cast<Derived<int>*>(pD))
    {
        std::cout << "non-const" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I would expect both dynamic_casts to return a valid pointer because the new type is less cv-qualified. Can anyone explain to me what I'm missing? Is there any way to identify a `Derived<XYZ>` ignoring cv-qualifier given a `Base` Pointer?

Answer (score 3):

From compiler perspective, `Derived<int>` and `Derived<const int>` are as far apart as `const char*` and `struct MyBox`. In other words, they bear no relationship between themselves.

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing which type the compiler is looking at.  Being *less const* refers to the type not the template parameter.  If you had

```
if(dynamic_cast<const Derived<int>*>(pD))
{
    std::cout << "const" << std::endl;
}

if(dynamic_cast<Derived<int>*>(pD))
{
    std::cout << "non-const" << std::endl;
}
```

Then both outputs would print.

A `something<sometype>` is a completely different type then a `something<some_other_type>` but a `const something<sometype>` is just a `const` version of a `something<sometype>`

Comment: I do not quite see how `something<sometype>` is so different from `something<const sometype>`? I was under the impression that const is enforced during compilation and basically gone afterwards. Why does the runtime check of dynamic cast still differentiate the 2?